# Layered navigation loads only part of information

Tags: magento2, attributes, layered-navigation

Thats one my attributes that should be visible in layered navigation:

```
 $eavSetup->removeAttribute(Product::ENTITY, 'supported_software');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Product::ENTITY,
            'supported_software',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'frontend_class' => 'required-entry',
                'label' => 'Supported software',

                'group' => 'Technical parameters',
                'sort_order' => 190,

                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'frontend' => '',
                'source' => '[vendor]\DbSchema\Model\SupportedSoftware\Adminhtml\Source\SupportedSoftware',

                'default' => 10,

                'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => false,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,

                'used_for_sort_by' => false,

                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,

                'searchable' => false,
                'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,



                'search_weight' => '',
                'filterable' => true,
                'filterable_in_search' => true,
                'comparable' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => 'downloadable,bundle',
                'is_used_for_promo_rules' => true,

                'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,

                'is_required_in_admin_store' => '',

                'system' => 0,
            ]
        );
```

Moreover this attribute has digit values for admin store and varchar values for frontend (default store view). But I don't think it is the problem here.
Layered navigation appears on frontend properly. I have in db about 40 products added programatically (tests) and all of them should have some values of this attribute  (I am adding these values for admin - but for frontend are being added simultanously). Sometimes my attributes shows up in layered navigation but sometimes not. If I add product from adminhtml manually values its values appears in layered navigation, but they erase former values. For example - if I have 10 product with values `x` and 10 with values `y` and I add product with value `z` in layered navigation after reindex/cache flush only appears results for only one product with value `z`.

All of my categories are anchored.

EDIT: Some attributes - escpecially the ones which have source model `Yes/No` in fact appear in lay nav in correct way and also react on changes of values of attributes properly.

EDIT: The same attribute if I added source model instead of options still doesn't appear in lay nav.

Comment: Is data loaded for layered navigation being saved in db somewhere or it's rather cached or what?

Comment: We had a similar issue some time ago. We would suggest you to check the eav_attribute and catalog_eav_attribute tables and compare "regular" Magento attributes with the attributes you have created programmatically. There can be a difference that gives you such results.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if being searchable is not a requirement if you want the attribute to be filterable.

What engine are you using ?

Comment: engine? I use Magento 2.1 and php 7.0

Comment: I mean what search engine MySQL, SolR, ES ?

Is the missing attribute searchable ?

Comment: I was testing it with many setting, also `searchable` but in my opinion it doesn't matter.